# How to mount btrfs subvolume?

Tags: debian, mount, btrfs

findmnt gives me this entry:

```
TARGET      SOURCE             FSTYPE  OPTIONS
|-/apps     /dev/md127[/.apps] btrfs   rw,noatime,nodiratime,nospace_cache,subvolid=259,subvol=/.apps
```

The .apps folder is a subvol. I have created a subvolume on the same level as .apps: .mysubvol

What is the correct mount command to create the entry for .mysubvol?

Best Regards
Jochen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution on stackexchange:

```
mount /dev/md127 -o subvol=.mysubvol /mysubvol
```

This gives me the exact same outpunt in findmnt as for the exisitng .apps folder.